# How to deserialize JSON from server side code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

suppose my json stored in string variable. my json look like

```
"{\"file\":\"dave\",\"type\":\"ward\"}"
```

the above data stored like in my string variable. now how can i deserialize this json data and read each component like file and type.

i tried with the below code but getting error

```
 var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

 var sData=jss.Deserialize<string>(json);
 string _file = sData[0].ToString();
 string _type = sData[1].ToString();
```

please guide my how can i extract each component like file and type after deserialize this from data in json format. thanks

---

**Rectification**

This way i solve this....here is whole client side & server side code.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#btnlogin').click(function (e) {
             var FeedCrd = {};
             FeedCrd["file"] = 'dave';
             FeedCrd["type"] = 'ward';

             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "CallASHX.ashx",
                 data: JSON.stringify(FeedCrd),
                 //data: { 'file': 'dave', 'type': 'ward' },
                 //dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) {
                     if (data == "SUCCESS");
                     {
                         alert('SUCCESS');
                     }

                 },
                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(textStatus);
                 }

             });
             return false;
         });
     });
 </script>

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        Dictionary<string,string> sData=jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(json);
        string _file = sData["file"].ToString();
        string _type = sData["type"].ToString();
        context.Response.Write("SUCCESS");
    }
```

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp

Comment: What's the error it gives you?

Comment: anyway i solve it and also post my solution. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way I have found is combining the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library with the new .net [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) object type:

```
string json = "{\"file\":\"dave\",\"type\":\"ward\"}";
dynamic jo = JObject.Parse(json);
string _file = jo.file;
string _type = jo.type;
```

Don't forget:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

This is a very simple way where you don't have to declare a strongly-typed object, therefore its simple to do on the fly.

Comment: this assumes op has .net 4 available

Comment: Precision on Adrian's comment: .net4 is needed here only because the answer is using the 'dynamic' keyword. Json.Net is able to run on earlier versions of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a class defined as:

```
public class YourJsonClass
{
    public string file {get;set;}
    public string type {get;set;}
}
```

Then, you'd desrialize like this:

```
YourJsonClass sData=jss.Deserialize<YourJsonClass>(json);
```

The data will be available in the `sData` object, according to `YourJsonClass` definition, thus, `sData.file` will hold the file property, and so on.

Comment: @Constantinius Thanks for the heads up, just updated the answer

Comment: anyway i solve it and also post my solution. please see question once again.thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I typically pass the JSON string to a function/method that takes a structured class as a parameter.

---

Javascript object

```
"{ q: {file:\"dave\", type:\"ward\"} }"
```

---

```
public class myClass
{
     private string _file = string.empty;
     public string file {
         get { return _file; }
         set { _file = value.trim(); }
       }

     private string _type = string.empty;
     public string type {
         get { return _type; }
         set { _type = value.trim(); }
       }
}
```

---

```
 public ClassTypeOrVariableType FunctionName(myClass q)
  {
     //do stuff here
  {
```